# Key Error after multiple annotations with Django

Tags: django

I am trying to calculate some statistics for my models. To do that I create some annotations that will help me do this:

```
# won
won_statuses = ["Won", "Half Won", "Cash Out"]
queryset = queryset.annotate(won=Case(When(status__name__in=won_statuses, then=1), default=0.0, output_field=DecimalField()))

# lost
lost_statuses = ["Lost", "Half Lost"]
queryset = queryset.annotate(lost=Case(When(status__name__in=lost_statuses, then=1), default=0.0, output_field=DecimalField()))

# lost_stake
queryset = queryset.annotate(lost_stake=F("lost") * F("stake"))
```

After that, I group the data by day, month or year and apply the annotation that will calculate the statistic:

```
target_dict = {"profit": Sum("profit"),
               "stake": Sum("stake"),
               "returns": Sum("returns"),
               "yield": Sum("profit") / Sum("stake"),
               "roi": Sum("returns") / Sum("stake"),
               "hitrate": Avg("won"),
               "count": Count("id")}

target = "profit"
group_by = "year"

data = queryset.annotate(group_by=Trunc("timestamp", group_by, output_field=DateField())) \
               .values("group_by") \
               .annotate(total_value=target_dict[target]) \
               .order_by("group_by") \
               .values_list("group_by", "total_value")
```

The issue is that every calculation that involves the custom annotations (won, lost, lost_stakes) shows me a Key Error: `.annotate(total_value=Avg("won"))`

Everything that was a field from the model is calculated correctly.

Shouldn't the custom annotations won, lost, lost_stake be included when I annotate with Trunc ?

If I have understood it right:

1.adds a field by truncating a date up to the appropriate significant    component (day, month, year):

```
.annotate(group_by=Trunc("timestamp", group_by, output_field=DateField()))
```

2.groups the values by the group_by value:

```
.values("group_by")
```

3.calcuates the function provided `(total_value=....)` for each of the groups:

```
.annotate(total_value=target_dict[target])
```

4. it orders the groups:

`.order_by("group_by")`

5.returns a list with the chosen fields:

```
.values_list("group_by", "total_value")
```

Have I misunderstood something ?

Comment: Well what is `target` here? LLooks like it is not a profit, stake, etc.

Comment: The error is quite like raised by the `target_dict[target]` in `.annotate(total_value=target_dict[target])`, so that means that the annotation never takes control here. Probably `tarket` thus has an *invalid* key.

Comment: I have added example values for target and group_by.

Shouldn't  .`annotate(group_by=Trunc("timestamp", group_by, output_field=DateField())) \
               .values("group_by")`  include the annotations calculated before ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are not propagating the annotated value down. Could you use the `value_list` and see if it solves your problem?

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(total_value=target_dict[target])


data = queryset.annotate(group_by=Trunc("timestamp", group_by, output_field=DateField())) \
           .values_list("group_by", "total_value")
```

Comment: The annotation for lost_stake before the Trunc works correctly. After the Trunc it seems like the lost_stake annotation shows a Key Error.

Comment: I guess then this is the issue. Could you put `.annotate(total_value=target_dict[target])` above the `values("group_by")`

Comment: I use `values("group_by")` to group the data in days, months or years and then apply `.annotate(total_value=target_dict[target])`.

Comment: You are using `values` which returns dictionary of only those which are mentioned, hence your other params are getting filtered. Can you break it into two parts and confirm it. I'm updating my answer, have a look

Comment: What is confusing is that profit and the other original model fields, meaning not the annotated ones, don't have any issue at all.

Comment: generally I prefer to write such complex operations in raw sql format, that gives me a lot of free hand and also optimisation. Django ORM are good, while doing small operations. That's my personal opinion.

Comment: I started doing this with the Django ORM, then went with Pandas, and now I am trying again with Django ORM. I haven't tried raw SQL so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178291/discussion-between-argo-and-giannisiordanou).